# Can not build project by ant tasksInitialization.xml:240: JAVA_HOME not found

Tags: java, ant

I try to build project by `ant` with this command `ant clean dist` and I get this message

```
BUILD FAILED ...source\tasksInitialization.xml:240: JAVA_HOME: ${JAVA_HOME_WL10.3.3} not found. Configuration is WL10.3.3
```

By the way, I set `JAVA_HOME` variable correctly. What is wrong?